# Is the space of convex functions a Polish space?

Tags: convex-analysis, descriptive-set-theory, skorohod-space

I'm working with continuous, increasing, convex functions (call the set $\mathcal{U}$) and viewing them as a subspace of $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ (perhaps this is not the best topology, recommendations welcome). Since $\mathcal{C}$ is Polish I sense that $\mathcal{U}$ is as well. I have a proof sketch (follows) and I hope someone can either give me a reference, or tell me I'm wrong, before I get too far into it.

Sketch: These functions can be recovered by their subdifferentials, which perhaps can be viewed as cadlag functions since each point will have a closed, convex interval of subderivatives. So, if I can find a homeomorphism between $\mathcal{U}$ and the space of cadlag functions with the Skorokhod topology, I get my answer by showing that non-decreasing functions form a closed subset in the Skorokhod topology (hopefully true).

I'm aware that cadlag with Skorokhod is not a TVS, which seems to rule out finding an isomorphism, but it doesn't seem essential that the algebraic structure is mapped . . .

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ is Polish and since $\mathcal{U}$ is a closed subset then it has to be Polish as well. Assuming that by "increasing" you actually mean "non-decreasing".

Comment: Oh . . . yah, indeed I am. That's embarrassing. I'll close the question.

Comment: I'd say it's more English than Polish xD

Answer (score 2):

New Answer:
As a closed subset of a Polish space, $\mathcal{U}$ is also Polish. 
Note that the limit of a sequence of convex, nondecreasing functions will also be non-decreasing and (weakly) convex.

Aside: 
Just trying to tie this off. I don't want to leave it hanging as unanswered.

Old Answer:
Obvious: $\mathcal{U}$ is closed.

Whoops. Thanks to "freakish" in comments above.

Comment: I'm trying to close my own question because the answer was provided in a comment. What is the best practice?

Comment: That depends on whether you believe the question will never be of any use to somebody else (then deleting it would be a good option) or it may be of use to somebody else (then providing an answer is the thing to do).